# Is there a way to not show parameters in url

Tags: parameter-passing

Is there a way to only show a clean url when doing a get request?

i.e. someone is send to a page:

```
http://domain.com/?param1=1&param2=2
```

And the user only sees :

```
http://domain.com
```

I tried it with a post-request but then you get these annoying pop-ups when someone refreshes the page or hits the back button.
Doing a post-redirect-get is also not possible since this increases the response time to much and the page is generated dynamically so it needs the parameters.

Comment: Making a session might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) when you are using Apache.
Or similar functionalities in other web servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to pass parameters from a client to a server:

- GET request; which you don't want to use
- POST body (includes post-redirect-get); you don't wan to use POST
- request header

The way to have a client pass arbitrary parameters in a request header is cookies.

Comment: It still has to work if cookies are disabled, so this is not an option. Why don't I want to use POST, isn't there a way to prevent the pop-up from happening? (without a PRG).

Comment: If preventing the pop-up isn't possible, would it be possible to auto-accept the form re-submit?